# Pandas DataFrame TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I am getting the following error:

> "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable"

It seems to have an issue with the `ipoURL = list(pd.DataFrame['bizURL'])` line.

```
import pandas as pd

filename = r'IPOData.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(filename)

ipoURL = []
ipoURL = list(pd.DataFrame['bizURL'])
print(ipoURL)
```

I am not sure why I am getting the TypeError anyone know why?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame`, creates a new object. To get the urls from the excel sheet that you just read, you should using `df['bizURL']`

Comment: Where do you define bizURL?

Comment: I have an excel sheet and bizURL is the header for a column in the sheet.  I changed it to df['bizURL'] and now I am getting a KeyError: 'bizURL'

Answer (score 0):

I converted the file to .csv and it worked by using pd.read_csv

```
filename = r'IPOData.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

ipoURL = list(df['bizURL'])

urlCount = len(ipoURL)
print(ipoURL)
```